Logging Exceptions with Custom Traces in Python
I'm working on a Python program where I need to log all exceptions (with custom logger on clickhouse), including their context, to aid in debugging. Instead of simply logging the final function that caused the problem, I've implemented a CustomException class to store the entire exception path, including details like which API was called, the CRUD operation performed, and any relevant parameters.
Here's a simplified version of the implementation:
class ExceptionSnippet:
    def __init__(self, file_name, func_name, msg, error_level):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.func_name = func_name
        self.msg = msg
        self.error_level = error_level

class CustomException(BaseException):
    error_code: int
    value: Any
    traces: list[ExceptionSnippet] = []

    def __init__(self, arg=None):
        if isinstance(arg, CustomException):
            self.error_code = arg.error_code
            self.value = arg.value
            self.traces = arg.traces

While hard coding this exceptions everything worked fine. But adding it to all crud functions seemed a bit over.
To automate this exception logging process across multiple functions, I've created a decorator called auto_logger. This decorator wraps the entire function, intercepts any exceptions, and adds them to the CustomException instance.
def auto_logger(file_name, func_name, error_code):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except CustomException as ex:
                ex.traces.append(
                    ExceptionSnippet(
                        file_name, func_name, ex.traces[-1].func_name, 'trace'
                    ))
                raise ex
                # Handle CustomException
            except Exception as ex:
                error = CustomException()
                error.error_code = error_code
                error.traces.append(ExceptionSnippet(
                    file_name, func_name, ex.args[0], 'error'
                ))
                raise error 
        return wrapper
    return decorator

The problem I'm encountering is that after applying this decorator to functions, the ex.traces list seems to retain previous exceptions, causing unexpected behavior. Here's an example log:
api/foo - crud_foo.change_bar - ERROR - Error validating bar [Error Code: 69420]
api/foo - crud_foo.change_bar - DEBUG - "some value"
api/foo - crud_foo.change_bar - TRACE - crud_foo.change_bar
api/foo - /prefix/change_bar - TRACE - change_bar 

After second call:
api/foo - crud_foo.change_password - ERROR - Ошибка валидации пароля [Error Code: 69420]
api/foo - crud_foo.change_password - DEBUG - "some value"
api/foo - crud_foo.change_password - TRACE - change_password
api/foo - crud_foo.change_password - ERROR - Ошибка валидации пароля [Error Code: 69420]
api/foo - crud_foo.change_password - DEBUG - "some value"
api/foo - crud_foo.change_password - TRACE - change_password
api/foo - /prefix/change_bar - TRACE - change_bar 

The same happens with other calls, piles of previos logs beneath new ones.
Any insights on why the ex.traces list accumulates previous exceptions would be greatly appreciated.
After implementing the decorator, the exceptions started to pile up. I tried deleting ex, and error.
I tried to reinitialize the logger (it was not a problem after all).
Only reloading my server returns it to one trace, second function call, and after still collects exceptions.
I expect that there is some method that flushes memory, or a decorator that reinitializes the decorated function or decorator itself after each use.

It looks a bit like you are trying to re-invent raise ... from ....

@KlausD. Yeah, but I need my code to run in problems, log the whole path, and log error_code without ever stoping. Whole django like traceback is not optimal, needed something clear for the team.

Asking my own question:
The reason for except CustomException as ex keeping old ex.traces in decorator is that wrapper initializes with program startup and keeps static values through the whole lifespan. Appending the ex.traces kept old traces as it was not re-initialized.
During __init__ I should have written self.traces = []
class CustomException(BaseException):
    error_code: int
    value: Any
    traces: list[ExceptionSnippet] = []

    def __init__(self, arg=None):
    self.traces = []    # new
        if isinstance(arg, CustomException):
            self.error_code = arg.error_code
            self.value = arg.value
            self.traces = arg.traces

Previously it wasn't a problem as try: ... except: ... was a part of the function where CustomException was initialized each call.
Did not think that worked like that. Was a surprise for me...
